# How to pass reference to an object as JSON in a POST in grails

Tags: rest, grails, grails-domain-class, grails-2.4

I have 2 classes `Person` and and `Designation`. I am using `@Resource` annotation to make them restful

```
            import grails.rest.Resource
            @Resource(formats=['json', 'xml'])

               class Person {
                               String name 
                               static belongsTo = [designation:Designation] 

                            static constraints = {  }
                            }
```

and `Designation` class is

```
                import grails.rest.Resource
                @Resource(formats=['json', 'xml'])

                   class Designation {
                                   Long designationId
                                   String name 


                                static constraints = {  }
                                }
```

Since I'm using grails default resource url mapping like

```
"/app/person"(resources: "person",  includes: ['index', 'show', 'save', 'update', 'delete', 'create', 'patch'])
```

I want to prform insert to Person object using POST request to `/app/person` with json data.
Since `designation` is belongs to another object , I need to pass only a reference to an existing  Designation object id
how do i pass this via json? what is the json format to do the same?
or can I access the params in beforeInsert() method of Person class , so that i can manually get designatioId , then find Designation object with that id , then assign it new Person object?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you add:

```
designation: { id: 123 }
```

to your person JSON, that should do the trick.